# Did Brit with rainbow happen in Kislev?

Tags: calendar, parashat-noach

I read on torahvort.com in [their article on Kislev](http://www.torahvort.com/torah-topics/kislev/) that the Brit with Noach about the rainbow happened in Kislev. We know from the end of [Ber 8:27](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8172#showrashi=true&v=27) that Noach left the ark on the 27th of the 2nd month, which [some identify](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8170#showrashi=true&v=11) as Cheshvan. It is plausible to say the Brit happened a few days later, but I see no reason to from the text. Does anyone know the source for this?

Comment: Well, he had to bring the sacrifices first, and that would taken some time for so many to bring and so few people to do it. And that assumes he just pulled the wood off of the ark.

Comment: @Yishai That could have taken weeks. Also, we don't know all the sacrifices happened first.

Comment: Jubilees assumes it happened in the third month. FWIW.

Comment: Could you please clarify on what you mean by "Jubilees"? Thanks for the comments. They are very logical, just wondering if there's a source that says this explicitly.

Comment: @DoubleAA, certainly but it suggests that a two-three day delay (at which point it would be in Kislev) is not unreasonable as a minimum. Since it is just an unsourced idea, I'm not putting it as an answer, I'm just pointing out it is consistent with the text.

Comment: @Cruzer Jubilees [is a book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jubilees) named _Jubilees_.

Comment: If Noach held by the post-Yetzias Mitzraim Halacha of watching a Karban for four days before offering it, then if he designated Karbanos immediately upon leaving the Teivah, the earliest he could have offered it was RC Kislev (if Cheshvan was 30 days, 2 Kislev otherwise).